# Teechart ZoomIn and ZoomOut Button

Tags: activex, teechart

I am using the zooming of TCHART. In our application we have a Next and Prev Button using which user can do Zoom and UndoZoom. Can you let me know how I can fire zoom and undozoom event on click on this two Buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either call the even methods directly (see code below) or use the calls that will fire the events (see commented code below).

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    TChart1_OnZoom
    'TChart1.Zoom.ZoomRect 0, 0, 100, 100
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    TChart1_OnUndoZoom
    'TChart1.Zoom.Undo
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnUndoZoom()
    TChart1.Header.Text.Clear
    TChart1.Header.Text.Add "Unzoom!"
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnZoom()
    TChart1.Header.Text.Clear
    TChart1.Header.Text.Add "Zoom!"
End Sub
```